# Executing a Script from Linux to a Mac

Tags: linux, macos, arduino, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is it possible to execute a script from a linux machine to run on a Mac, using either Python or Bash? I have a raspberry pi with an arduino, when a sensor or an even occurs from the arduino i want to run a script to do something, "ie: run a "say" command" on my mac, any way of doing this? and how would it be done? i would not like to connect the arduino to the mac, since location is an issue, so it has to be done from the raspberrypi

Answer (score 0):

ssh. if your mac runs sshd. 
you can

```
rasbery> ssh $account@$mac_IP $command
```